# HtmlAgilityPack select subnodes value

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

HTML string contains the exact string

```
<div class="XKa d-k-l"><span class="VTb d-k-l"></span></div><div class="pha d-k-l"><div ><div>Hello World </div>
```

I want to retrieve the Hello World from a div.

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
var item = 
     HTMLContent.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='XKa d-k-l']//span[@class='VTb d-k-l']//div[@class='pha d-k-l']")
                .InnerHtml;
```

> Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Cant figure out the correct syntax Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div[@class='pha d-k-l']` is not descendant of `div[@class='XKa d-k-l']`, the relation is `sibling`s instead `ancestor`-`descendant`. You can try using `following-sibling` axis like so :

```
//div[@class='XKa d-k-l']/following-sibling::div[@class='pha d-k-l']
```

**[working demo example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zvLx5s) :**

```
var html = @"<div class='XKa d-k-l'><span class='VTb d-k-l'></span></div><div class='pha d-k-l'><div><div>Hello World </div></div></div>";
var HTMLContent = new HtmlDocument();
HTMLContent.LoadHtml(html);
var item = HTMLContent.DocumentNode
            .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='XKa d-k-l']/following-sibling::div[@class='pha d-k-l']").InnerHtml;
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**output :**

```
<div><div>Hello World </div></div>
```

**update :**

You can add the `span` check like this :

```
//div[@class='XKa d-k-l'][span/@class='VTb d-k-l']/following-sibling::div[@class='pha d-k-l']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to add span as well <span class="VTb d-k-l"> because in the html string it has for example `<div class="XKa d-k-l"><span class="ZSb d-k-l"></span></div><div class="pha d-k-l">` need to make sure that after div there is a specific span I tried to do this: `.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='XKa d-k-l']//span[@class='VTb d-k-l']/following-sibling::div[@class='pha d-k-l']").InnerHtml` but it doest work

Comment: I tried this too `.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='VTb d-k-l']/following-sibling::div[@class='pha d-k-l']").InnerHtml` shouldnt this work?

Comment: No, because the target `div` is **not sibling** of `span`. Instead, the target `div` is sibling of the `div` that is parent of the `span`